# Where to convert date to UTC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering which area would make the most sense to convert dates to UTC and back again. We store dates in UTC and convert to a users local time zone. Right now I think putting it in the repository layer makes the most sense because you don't need to remember to convert it each time you create service layer methods that require it. My teammate suggest putting it in the service layer because it is a business rule...

Where would you put these conversion function? Service layer or Repository layer? This could include looping through a list of objects and doing a convert on each one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where would you put these conversion function? Service layer or Repository layer?

In neither of those layers. I would put it in the view model. If the view requires showing dates in local timezone and your dates are stored in UTC in the model then the view model is the perfect place to format data that is being shown on the view.

Comment: All dates will be displayed in local time. I can't think of any instance they wouldn't.

Comment: Yes, the conversion function should be called with the time parameter in UTC directly from the view. You can store the function itself as an HtmlHelper, so that you can use it as such: `<%= Html.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, offset) %>`

Comment: Agreed. You may have logic in the Repos and elsewhere in the domain model that may need to compare dates. In these cases it's best (and far less messy) to do all logic on UTC dates. Do the translation just under the user (UI) to and from local time.

Comment: Maxim: Your comment (do it in the View) is actually different from what Darin suggests (do it in the View Model). Darin: Could you show an example?  Would you suggest having a constructor in the view model that populates a "LocalTime" DateTime property?